# xdg-open is installed yet also is not installed

Tags: linux, which, xdg-open

```
$ xdg-open
The program 'xdg-open' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install xdg-utils

$ sudo apt-get install xdg-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xdg-utils is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 89 not upgraded.

$ whereis xdg-open
xdg-open: /usr/bin/xdg-open /usr/bin/X11/xdg-open /usr/share/man/man1/xdg-open.1.gz

$ which xdg-open

$ xdg-open
The program 'xdg-open' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install xdg-utils
```

No, I didn't mean "recursion".

I'm on Linux Mint 15 MATE, but instead of MATE I'm using the i3 window manager.

**Edit taking @slm's advice**

```
$ type -a xdg-open
type: xdg-open not found
```

But it's in /usr/bin/xdg-open.  I checked.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/xdg-open
xdg-utils: /usr/bin/xdg-open
```

The next one was even more interesting.

```
$ dpkg -S xdg-open
git-annex: /usr/share/doc/git-annex/html/bugs/Fix_for_opening_a_browser_on_a_mac___40__or_xdg-open_on_linux__47__bsd__63____41__.html
xdg-utils: /usr/bin/xdg-open
xdg-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/xdg-open.1.gz
```

The bug-fix is just a mail archive of a patch for an OSX problem.  Anyway, I guess I could try using the full path:

```
$ /usr/bin/xdg-open
/usr/bin/xdg-open: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Someone with 300+ reputation might like to create a more appropriate tag.

Comment: +1 This made me laugh. Maybe it's a zen koan, in apt form?

Comment: I found what's wrong.  Just writing up an answer.  Wouldn't have found it without @slm's suggestion of `dpkg -S xdg-open`.

Comment: See updates to my answer on how to reinstall a broken package safely on Debian/Ubuntu based distros.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like your package database is screwed up. First I'd identify all the versions of `xdg-open` that you have on your system. The `type` should always be used for doing this task, [never rely on `which` or `whereis`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then).

#### Example

Identify all `xdg-open`'s.

```
$ type -a xdg-open
xdg-open is /usr/bin/xdg-open
```

Find out which packages they're a part of.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/xdg-open
xdg-utils: /usr/bin/xdg-open
```

You'll want to either repeat the above `dpkg -S ..` for each match returned by `type -a` *or* use this `dpkg -S ..` search instead.

```
$ dpkg -S xdg-open
xdg-utils: /usr/bin/xdg-open
xdg-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/xdg-open.1.gz
```

I would do each, one at a time.

#### Reinstalling xdg-utils

If you'd like to refresh this package's installation do this:

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall xdg-utils
```

Comment: I shouldha waited!  Don't worry - I cancelled the uninstall asap and managed to recover by pasting the list of programs it said it would uninstall into a `sudo apt-get install` command.  Phew.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @slm's tip, I tracked this down.

A while back,  I followed some bad advice to make `chromium-browser` the default on Linux Mint.  The advice was, delete `usr/bin/xdg-open`, then create a symlink in its place to `chromium-browser`.

It sure made Chromium the default browser.  It made Chromium the default for lots of things.

Since then, of course, I installed the official Chrome for Linux from Google.  It worked as the default automatically and I forgot about the kludge.

Unfortunately, it's hard to fix.  You can remove the symlink okay, but how to retrieve the original?  `sudo apt-get install xdg-utils` doesn't bother because it thinks it's already up-to-date.  `sudo apt-get remove xdg-utils` is currently busy uninstalling virtually my entire system.

Comment: Don't remove it!!! See my updates.